# How to get error statusCode from `MoyaError`?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift, moya

I'm using a `Moya`, `Moya_ModelMapper` and `RxSwift` to perform network requests.
Here is my example code:

```
let provider = RxMoyaProvider<MyEndpoint>()
let observable: Observable<RegistrationResponse> = provider.request(.register(firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "", password: "")).mapObject(type: RegistrationResponse.self)
observable.subscribe {
    [weak self] (event: Event<RegistrationResponse>) in
    switch event {
    case .next(let response):
        print(response)
    case .error(let error):
        print(error)
    case .completed:
        break
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I don't know how to get an error code when I receive for example a `409` status code response type from the server. 
If I print the error I will get:

`jsonMapping(Status Code: 409, Data Length: 0)`

but I don't know how to get this status code by code. The error is `MoyaError` which is an Enum type. Here it's a [source code](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Sources/Moya/MoyaError.swift) of MoyaError.

Thanks!

Comment: `error.response.statuscode` could that be it? Since the response does contain a statuscode. And the error contains response.

Comment: `(error as! MoyaError).response?.statusCode` works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Migrating from the comment

A Moya error does not contain an error code directly, they do contain MoyaResponses which do in turn contain the error code.

First case the error as as MoyaError

```
let moyaError: MoyaError? = error as? MoyaError
```

The optional MoyaError will contain an optional response, using optional chaining we get:

```
let response : Response? = moyaError?.response
```

Lastly we can get the response its status code.

```
let statusCode : Int? = response?.statusCode
```

Comment: Wow!! your answer saved my life... Thank you thousand times!!

Comment: I have the error (Time Out) and `moyaError.response` is nil. How can I check what exact error it is?

Answer (score 7):

For the ones who had a **nil** moyaError.response, here is a way to get the **errorCode**

```
 if let error = ((error as? MoyaError)?.errorUserInfo["NSUnderlyingError"] as? Alamofire.AFError)?.underlyingError as? NSError, error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain, error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet || error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut || error.code == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost {
                   print("not connected")
      }
```