# how to get the error response from MoyaError

Tags: swift3, rx-swift, moya

similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911565/how-to-get-error-statuscode-from-moyaerror) but this time i need to retrieve the JSOn response of the server.

here is my existing code:

```
return Observable.create{ observer in
            let _ = self.provider
                .request(.getMerchantDetails(qrId: qrId))
                .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
                .mapJSON()
                .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                    observer.onNext(RQRMerchant(json: JSON(response)))
                }, onError: { error in
                    observer.onError(error)
                })
            return Disposables.create()
```

my question is: I can get the error response code 404 by `error.localizedDescription` But I also want to get the JSON response of the 404 HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

I've been faced with the same problem, and for me the easiest and cleanest solution was to extend `MoyaError` to include a property for the decoded error object. In my case I'm using `Decodable` objects, so you could write something like this for a decodable `BackendError` representing the error you may get from your server:

```
extension MoyaError {
    public var backendError: BackendError? {
        return response.flatMap {
            try? $0.map(BackendError.self)
        }
    }
}
```

If you instead prefer to directly deal with JSON you can invoke the `mapJSON`method instead of mapping to a `Decodable`.

Then you just have to do the following to get the error information for non successful status codes:

```
onError: { error in
    let backendError = (error as? MoyaError).backendError
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the response of your server is also contained in a JSON, that means that your `onNext` emissions can be successful JSON responses or invalid JSON responses.

### Check the validity of the response using `do` operator

You can check for the validity of the response by doing the following:

```
return Observable.create{ observer in

        let _ = self.provider
            .request(.getMerchantDetails(qrId: qrId))
            .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            .mapJSON()
            .do(onNext: { response in 
                 let isValidResponse : Bool = false // check if response is valid

                  if !isValidResponse {
                      throw CustomError.reason
                  }
            })
            .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                observer.onNext(RQRMerchant(json: JSON(response)))

            }, onError: { error in
                observer.onError(error)

            })

        return Disposables.create()
```

1. Use the `do` operator
2. Check if the `onNext` emission is indeed a valid emission
3. Throw an error if it is invalid, signifying that the observable operation has failed.

### Response validation

To keep your response validation code in the right place, you can define a class function within your response class definition that verifies if it is valid or not:

```
class ResponseOfTypeA {
    public class func isValid(response: ResponseOfTypeA) throws {
        if errorConditionIsTrue {
            throw CustomError.reason
        }
    }
}
```

So that you can do the following:

```
    // Your observable sequence
    .mapJSON()
    .do(onNext: ResponseOfTypeA.isValid)
    .subscribe(onNext: { response in 
        // the rest of your code

    })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time. I get what you want to say to me, but what I want to do is get the JSON response of the sever with a 404 HTTP response.