# Moya.Error/Swift How to get the response body of an error

Tags: swift, moya

I already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851032/how-to-get-the-error-response-from-moyaerror) but my wordings were poor.

Assuming my API response code is 404, My goal is to get the JSON response body of that error API. Sure I can get the response code, but how about the response body?

Comment: you are using Alamofire